# how to split an array of strings in java

Tags: java, arrays, split, date-format

I have an Array of String type which holds columns from a database that holds values of date and time as 2014-11-12 16:08:48. Now I have to split the array so that I retrieve only the time value, i.e. 16:08:48. How can I apply split on the array?

Thanks in advance.

Code through which I retrieve my column values is

```js
public String[] getChartTime() throws SQLException {
  List < String > timeStr = new ArrayList < String > ();
  String atime[] = null;
  getConnection();
  try {
    con = getConnection();


    String sql = "exec vcs_gauge @gauge_name=?,@first_rec_time=?,@last_rec_time=?";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("date is " + df.format(currentDate));
    clstmt = con.prepareCall(sql);
    clstmt.setString(1, "vs3_bag");
    clstmt.setString(2, "2014-09-01 10:00:00");
    clstmt.setString(3, "2014-09-01 11:00:00");
    clstmt.execute();
    rs = clstmt.getResultSet();

    while (rs.next()) {
      // Just get the value of the column, and add it to the list
      timeStr.add(rs.getString(1));

    }

  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\nException in  Bean in getDbTable(String code):" + e);
  } finally {
    closeConnection();
  }
  // I would return the list here, but let's convert it to an array
  atime = timeStr.toArray(new String[timeStr.size()]);
  


  return atime;


}
```

Now I want to split the timestr array so that I get time only, and no date.

Comment: Some code to this question? How far have you gotten on your own?

Comment: My array has 3600 values and all are in "2014-11-12 16:18:48" form.Values in array are fetched from database.I don't want to print it on console but want to display the value of time on x-axis of a chart.Therefore i need these splitted values to be stored in array of string type only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `String.split()` method using `space` as the delimiter. You can do that by using code below:

```
String[] atime = new String[3600];
Iterator<String> it = timeStr.iterator();
int i = 0;
while(it.hasNext()) {
    atime[i] = it.next().toString().split("\\s")[1]; /* stores each time in each index of atime */
    i++;
}
```

After doing this the result will be in the String array `atime[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this with the following code:

```
// Just get the value of the column, and add it to the list
timeStr.add(rs.getString(1).split(" ")[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by using substring .The code is

```js
 while (rs.next()) {
   // Just get the value of the column, and add it to the list
   timeStr.add(rs.getString(1).substring(11, 16));

 }
```